# prohibit publish Azure Function directly from Visual Studio Code

Tags: azure-functions

Is it possible somehow to control how to prohibit publishing Azure Function directly from Visual Studio Code? I would like to have only possibility to publish function from repo from Azure DevOps.

Comment: can't you apply a resource group or resource level policy to stop deployment action except using some particular service principle?

Comment: Would be nice to have a way to turn this off in the vscode addon. I don't want people selecting the wrong Function App in the pop-ups and nuke the wrong one, but to use the npm script in my package.json instead.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a particular setting that you could set. Under the hood the VS Code deployment uses similar Kudo APIs as a release task on a Azure DevOps build agent.

What you can do:

- Limit write access in general, especially on production environments. Usually no physical user should have (long standing) write access, only Service Principles. This way you can ensure that no user will be able to deploy from VS Code or just anywhere. Note: This is a general recommendation you should follow no matter what.
- Use [IP restrictions on the SCM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-ip-restrictions#restrict-access-to-an-scm-site) (deployment) endpoint of the Function app. If you use self-hosted build agents in ADO, that would be a valid approach since you would know the public IP, or even better, put the build agent on a VNET and only allow access to the SCM site from that subnet